# How to put the focus of an input in a form-field with ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, focus

I am faced with a problem, I want in my code, to put the focus on a conditioned input
based on data from an observable. In my example I just set a boolean to `true` in the `ngOnInit()`.

```
export class InputOverviewExample implements OnInit {
  bool: boolean;

  @ViewChild("input1", { static: true }) input1: MatInput;
  @ViewChild("input2", { static: true }) input2: MatInput;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bool = true;
    this.input1.nativeElement.focus();
    this.input2.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

And I noticed that the focus is not working when a `mat-form-field` is conditioned.

```
<form class="example-form">
  <h3>Without *ngIf :</h3>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput #input1 placeholder="Auto focus" value="Test_input1" />
  </mat-form-field>

  <h3>With *ngIf :</h3>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width" *ngIf="bool">
    <input matInput #input2 placeholder="Auto focus" value="Test_input2" />
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

[**StackBlitz link**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-put-the-focus-of-an-input-in-a-form-field-with-ngif?file=src/app/input-overview-example.html)

Someone would have a solution to this problem

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need understand ViewChild {static:true} and {static:false} and {read}

So, first define your ViewChild as

```
@ViewChild("input1", { static: false,read:ElementRef }) input1: ElementRef;
@ViewChild("input2", { static: false,read:ElementRef }) input2: ElementRef;
```

The `static:false` makes that Angular check if is under a *ngIf

The `read:ElementRef` makes that your "input1" and "input2" are saw as ElementRef, not as MatInput

The second thing that you need is how Angular works. Angular execute all the actions and refresh the application, so if you write

```
this.bool = true;
this.input2.nativeElement.focus(); //<--this.input2 is undefined
```

this.input2 is undefined because Angular has not repaint the application, so you need enclosed by setTimeout -you can think about setTimeout like you say to Angular "hey, don't forget that after refresh the appication, you need make this another instuctions"- or use [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef).

So

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.bool = true;
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.input1.nativeElement.focus();
      this.input2.nativeElement.focus();
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.bool = true;
    if(...){
        this.input1.nativeElement.focus();
    }
    else{
        this.input2.nativeElement.focus();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `QueryList` to query element

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild,   
QueryList,
  ViewChildren, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
import { MatInput } from "@angular/material";
import {startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';

/**
 * @title Basic Inputs
 */
@Component({
  selector: "input-overview-example",
  styleUrls: ["input-overview-example.css"],
  templateUrl: "input-overview-example.html"
})
export class InputOverviewExample implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  bool: boolean;
  @ViewChild("input1", { static: true }) input1: MatInput;
  // @ViewChild("input2", { static: true }) input2: MatInput;
  @ViewChildren('input2') input2: QueryList<ElementRef>;

constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {

}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.bool = true;
    this.input1.nativeElement.focus();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     this.input2.changes
     .pipe(
        startWith(true),
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.input2.forEach((elementRef: ElementRef) => {
          if(elementRef) {
             elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
             this.cd.detectChanges();
          }
        });
      });
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-put-the-focus-of-an-input-in-a-form-field-with-ng-njwvip?file=src/app/input-overview-example.ts)